# “Mole concept" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I realized that we have a [mole-concept](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mole-concept) tag but no [mole](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mole) tag. I don't really see the point in having *concept* appended to the tag (we don't have [reaction-concept](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reaction-concept) or [organic-chemistry-concept](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-chemistry-concept)), and though I cannot think of a reason someone would create it that way, there must be one…

So, what do you think?

Comment: Rename+synonym to [tag:mole] works for me.

Comment: Can you think of an example when a [tag:mole] would be used *without* [tag:homework]?  I'm not sure the tag is even needed.

Comment: @bobthechemist yes, it is likely to be used mostly on homework questions… but “homework” is an outlier in the tagging system, because it's a meta-tag (the only meta-tag we have). Thus, I think we should continue to use the “mole” tag where needed.

Comment: @bobthechemist We can have basic non-homework conceptual questions. See the top two [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mole-concept+-homework)

Comment: @F'x Think we have enough consensus? Not like we get vote scores more than three on this meta

Comment: @ManishEarth I've merged, but did not create a synonym (I'll do so if the tag reappears)